# How to set cookies using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I don't have an idea how to implement simple CRUD using cookies.

First question: What to put instead of @user? I have only this:
My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth %>
  <%= f.input :phone_number %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Next question: how to properly send value from form field to cookies[].
Before I only used params method(e.g. clients_params) and instance variables.

```
  def create
    cookies[:first_name] = params[:first_name]
    cookies[:last_name] = params[:last_name]
    cookies[:date_of_birth] = params[:date_of_birth]
    cookies[:phone_number] = params[:phone_number]

    redirect_to 'clients/show'
  end

  def show
    @first_name = cookies[:first_name]
    @last_name = cookies[:last_name]
    @date_of_birth = cookies[:date_of_birth]
    @phone_number = cookies[:phone_number]
  end
```

I can't find any good tutorial about cookies and how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the docs of [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), specifically this example of how the ERB is compiled to HTML:

```
simple_form_for @user do |f|
  f.input_field :name
  f.input_field :remember_me, as: :boolean
end
```

becomes

```
<form>
  ...
  <input class="string required" id="user_name" maxlength="255" name="user[name]" size="255" type="text">
  <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="boolean optional" id="user_published" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
  </label>
</form>
```

Notice how `f.input_field :name` becomes `<input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">`

The `name="user[remember_me]"` part is important, because the `name` attribute determines how the param gets read in rails. If it was just simply `name='remember_me'`, then `params[:remember_me]` would work, but this is using some special syntax to nest objects. The incoming param will be `params[:user][:remember_me]`

In summary, use `params[:user][<param_name>]` in the controller and not just `params[<param_name>]`.

Using a [secure-params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) method could help as well, for example:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:remember_me, :name, etc)
end

# in controller
cookies[:name] = user_params[:name]
```